# alterar uma propriedade de um array de objetos sem fazer loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js-2

Bom dia, tenho um array de objetos com varias propriedades e uma delas é a propriedade data que gostaria de converter. Porém gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem usar um loop.

```
var arr = [{data: 2018/01/02, nome: 'Teste}, 
           {data: 2018/03/03, nome: ' Outro Teste},
           {data: 2019/02/29, nome: 'João'} ... ]
```

preciso de um novo array, onde a propriedade data seja no formato DD-MM-AA e mantenha as demais propriedades inalteradas. Se alguém souber como fazer isso sem necessidade de fazer um for agradeço

Comment: É possível, mas ai você teria que escrever uma linha alterando o valor pra cada um dos indexes da array. Não entendo por que não usar um loop/laço

Comment: na verdade é um array muito extenso, imaginei que haveria alguma forma mais rápida, sem precisar percorrer através de um loop

Comment: O loop foi feito exatamente pra fazer ações extensas de forma rápida.
Pra substituir isso como você quer só precisa de 2 linhas de código bem dizer

Comment: @ElisangelaCarlaDESouza seja qualquer sintaxe que escolhas, parencendo ou não um loop, vais ter sempre de sempre de aceder a cada obj e converter a data... É um loop, aqui tens vários: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration